# Separate a list into values with common prefix and uncommon prefix - python

Tags: python

I have the following input:

```
['.apple.pie.desc','.apple.pie.bore', '.apple.key.dcx','set.pie.desc']
```

And I wish to get:
get common_prefix `.apple.`

```
['.apple.pie.desc','.apple.pie.bore', '.apple.key.dcx'],['set.pie.desc']
```

code:
line = {'.set.apple.pie.desc': '2','.set.apple.pie.bore': '4', '.set.apple.key.dcx': '3','set.pie.desc': '2' }

res = [list(i) for j,i in itertools.groupby(line.keys(), lambda x:x.rpartition('.')[0])]

print(res) - [['.set.apple.pie.desc', '.set.apple.pie.bore'], ['.set.apple.key.dcx'], ['set.pie.desc']]

But it should be [['.set.apple.pie.desc', '.set.apple.pie.bore','.set.apple.key.dcx'] , ['set.pie.desc']]

Comment: You can use a dict, where key would the prefix and value would be array of value's for each prefix

Comment: Please show us your attempt.

Comment: line = {'.set.apple.pie.desc': '2','.set.apple.pie.bore': '4', '.set.apple.key.dcx': '3','set.pie.desc': '2' }

res = [list(i) for j,i in itertools.groupby(line.keys(), lambda x:x.rpartition('.')[0])]

print(res)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
l = ['.apple.pie.desc','.apple.pie.bore', '.apple.key.dcx','set.pie.desc']
common_pre , uncommon_pre= [], []
pre = '.apple.'
for value in l:
    common_pre.append(value) if pre in value else uncommon_pre.append(value)
```

**Output:**

```
['.apple.pie.desc', '.apple.pie.bore', '.apple.key.dcx']
['set.pie.desc']
```

Comment: Forgot to mention common_prefix is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
import itertools
import re
s = ['.apple.pie.desc','.apple.pie.bore', '.apple.key.dcx','.set.pie.desc']
longest_prefix = ""
for i,j in itertools.groupby(s, lambda x:x.rpartition('.')[0]):
    if len(i.split(".")[1]) > len(longest_prefix):
        longest_prefix = i.split(".")[1]
new_s = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(s, key=lambda x:bool(re.findall(longest_prefix, x)))]
print(new_s)
```

The output is:

```
[['.apple.pie.desc', '.apple.pie.bore', '.apple.key.dcx'], ['set.pie.desc']]
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say, The common_prefix is not defined.

Comment: @DheerajreddyBonthu so where do you get it from?

Comment: So we have to take the longest common prefix ignoring the string that does not match at all. I could not find a logic for this. Thanks

Comment: @DheerajreddyBonthu I fixed the code, now it search for the longest prefix. see my edits

Comment: Thank you so much.Will try that @David S

Answer (score 0):

The approach that will give you the best performance is to use statistics.mode to determine the most common prefix and numpy.array to split your list into common and other prefixes.

```
from statistics import mode 
from numpy import array

li = ['.apple.pie.desc','.apple.pie.bore', '.apple.key.dcx','set.pie.desc']

li_prefix =[el.split('.')[1] for el in li]
most_common_prefix = mode(li_prefix)
li_mask = array(li_prefix)==most_common_prefix

li_common = array(li)[li_mask]
li_other = array(li)[~li_mask]

print(list(li_common))
print(list(li_other))
```

Output:

```
['.apple.pie.desc', '.apple.pie.bore', '.apple.key.dcx']
['set.pie.desc']
```